# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object related to opencv

Tags: python

I have written the code below to do following thing

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('1.png')
pyautogui.click('1.png', duration=0.5)

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('2.png')
pyautogui.click('2.png')
```

1. Locate 1.png and click it
2. After clicking 1.png, wait for the screen to come up
3. Then locate 2.png and click it

However, code would simply do up to 1 and stop like this

```
PS C:\\startcoding\> C:/Users/konpa/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/startcoding/test.py
```

I thought at first that it may be time related problem, but as I tinkered it around,

```
PS C:\startcoding> &
C:/Users/konpa/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/pythTraceback (most recent call last):
    pyautogui.click('2.png')
\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 598, in wrapper
  File "C:\Users\konpa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 980, in click
    x, y = _normalizeXYArgs(x, y)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

this would come up

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How is this related to OpenCV?

Comment: Unpacking `None` obviously isn't going to work, you need to find out why you don't get anything that can be unpacked there. Try to extract a [mcve] and perhaps step through the code with a debugger. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].